# Django Rest Framework Testing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I have a LoginSerializer that has the block of code as below

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    username = attrs.get('username', '')
    password = attrs.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active is False:
            raise AuthenticationFailed(
                'Account is disabled, contact admin')
        if not user.is_verified:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Email is not verified')
        return {
            'username': user.username,
            'firstname': user.firstname,
            'lastname': user.lastname,
            'role': user.role,
            'tokens': user.tokens
        }
    else:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials, try again')
```

and a test case as below;

```
class UserLoginTest(BaseTest):
    def test_inactive_user_can_login(self):
        self.client.post(
            self.register_public, data=valid_user, format='json')
        user = User.objects.get(username=valid_user['username'])
        user.is_verified = True
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        response = self.client.post(
            self.login_url, valid_login_user, format='json')
        print(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

When I run the test with **is_active = False** I get Invalid credentials, try again. Why is it that when is_active=False the user is not found even though the user is there? Same with when I try to login from swagger.

**EDIT**

I have read that I can use

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']
```

then I will be able to check for is_active manually otherwise django handles that and returns a **None**. What are the dangers of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are using [`.authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users) which by default goes through all backends listed in [`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.backends). If not listed in settings, `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` is used, this backend verifies `.is_active()` field:

```
...
def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
    """
    Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
    that attribute are allowed.
    """
    is_active = getattr(user, "is_active", None)
    return is_active or is_active is None
...
```

That snippet runs before your verification and returns `None` to `user` variable. So, it fails on `if user` condition (user is None) thus `raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials, try again')`

About [`AllowAllUsersModelBackend`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend) the only thing it does is override this method to allow inactive users to login:

```
class AllowAllUsersModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        return True
```

The only risk i can see, is using this backend and not checking `.is_active()` field manually. Unless if it is intended that inactive users can login into your system.

Comment: I instead checked if is_active is True and login or present an error message if Falses.